# Key mapping issue with Left 'CTRL' key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys, xev

My **Left CTRL works with some apps but not others.**  I did a **'xev'**  to check it out and got back a strange result.

Xev

**The right <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key works with all apps**

```
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0x179, subw 0x0, time 120780392, (246,-446), root:(301,352),
    state 0x10, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    root 0x179, subw 0x0, time 120780545, (246,-446), root:(301,352),
    state 0x14, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

**The left <kbd>ctrl</kbd> Key has issues with some apps**

```
FocusOut event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x2000001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967211 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

What's causing this?  Is there anyway to fix it?  I'm just trying to get the **Left <kbd>ctrl</kbd>** to act "normal".

My system stats:

```
cat /etc/os-release 

NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal

cat /proc/version

Linux version 5.15.0-56-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-102) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #62~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 22 21:24:20 UTC 2022
```

**UPDATE:**

**I created a new user account** on the same machine and ran the **xev** test again.  **The left <kbd>ctrl</kbd> Key seems to work**. Working output with using the new user is below.

**The question is how do I fix this within my main login user?**

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0xe00001,
    root 0x179, subw 0x0, time 123177372, (157,-76), root:(418,498),
    state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0xe00001,
    root 0x179, subw 0x0, time 123177509, (157,-76), root:(418,498),
    state 0x4, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

**The question is how do I fix this within my main login user?**

Answer (score 1):

Ok,very strange but I found it

Launch **'Tweaks'**

And **disable** Pointer Location

[image: img1]